# Стоит ли вообще заморачиваться на счет отключенного javascript

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript

HI. Вопрос: Стоит ли на самом деле учитывать то, что у пользователя может быть отключен javascript при разработке web приложения. Кто-нибуть может привести статистику отключенного javascript у пользователей? Помню себя когда был обычным пользователем, такой проблем вообще не было (даже не знал, что это такое). Может эта проблемы высосана из пальца? У меня опыт в разработке не большой поэтому все еще сомневаюсь по этому поводу.

Comment: Ещё бы приплюсовал к этому вопросу случаи когда JS включён, но jQuery не подгрузилось\не запустилось\не сработало по каким либо причинам (такое реально?) + хотелось бы проекцию этих вопросов на мобильный браузеры

Comment: "Помню себя когда был обычным пользователем" +1

Comment: +1? Не почувствовал)))

Comment: Присоединяюсь и хочу спросить - нужно ли заключать теги скрипта на странице в условные комментарии?

Comment: У меня стоит `NoScript`. С точки зрения сайта это выглядит как выключенный javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Конечно есть разные ситуации, когда стоит такой случай учитывать, и когда можно не заморачиваться. Если отсутствие JS у пользователя может повлечь потери средств (ну например оплата), ну или любая другая потеря (атомный реактор взорвется) то тогда надо предусматривать.

А вот в большинстве случаев, можно принебречь, все же на дворе 2013ый год, тут даже на счет <IE7 можно не заморачиваться )

Статистика, так статистика )

посмотрел на Яндекс.Метрике у своих сайтов:

- у первого: у 98,8% пользователей включен JavaScript
- у второго: у 99,1% пользователей включен JavaScript

У знакомого спросил (у него сайт пожирнее будет >160к различных пользователей), у него тоже в районе 98% включен JavaScript.

Мой совет - ставить к примеру ЯндексМетрику и там уже для своего сайта смотреть )

Comment: Вопрос в том и заключается существуют ли вообще пользователи с отключенным javascript?

Comment: где статистика?

Comment: дополнил ответ. :) А вопрос то основной был в названии темы: 
"Стоит ли вообще заморачиваться на счет отключенного javascript"

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум базовые функции сайта (переход по ссылкам, отправка форм и тп) необходимо делать так, что бы они работали без JS. Это совсем не сложно и считается хорошим тоном =)

А на счет подгрузки jQuery - нужно грузить ее со своего сервера и тогда будете уверенны что он подгрузится. Или грузить с внешних сервисов (их офф сайт, гугловский источник или яндекса), а если не подгрузился, то подключать свой. Это может понадобится в том случае, если нужно оптимизировать скорость загрузки страницы. Т.к. у пользователя с большой вероятностью уже есть закешированная копия скрипта из внешнего источника, то он не будет 2й раз грузить с вашего сайта